# How to identify and fix vulnerability for TLS ROBOT on AIX server

Tags: aix

Vulnerability scan shows that my server (**server1821**) is currently vulnerable to TLS ROBOT

Server is AIX.

How do I check for this vulnerability and how to fix this?

I checked with my vender and I got the reply as :

*Does the scan report which ports are vulnerable?  Those applications using TLS protocol with RSA ciphers need to be altered so they no longer use RSA.   We need to do this at the application level.*

Not sure about this suggestion.

The TLS ROBOT advisory site ((https://robotattack.org/) doesn't have any answers with respect to AIX.

A simple command shows this"

```
serverl1821 2 % cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config |grep -i rsa
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
serverl1821 3 %
```

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

The vulnerability may have nothing to do with `ssh`. You should update `GSKit` package. This is the package which implement SSL/TLS in AIX. And do not forget to restart web/application server.

Answer (score 0):

Your application vendor is absolutely correct. First of all you have to ask you security guys, where they found the vulnerability. Not only the server name, but also the port.

Then the problem may be in one of the following component:

- OpenSSH
- OpenSSL
- IBM GSKit
- Java

Every of the components requires different tuning to disable RSA ciphers.

To make it more complex every application can come with their own SSL/TLS library and their own set of settings.